# Spring Aspect Advice @Test methods

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I have a test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)
@Transactional
@Component
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        simpleService.test();
    }

}
```

I want make an aspect in order to monitor test method invocation

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.junit.Test)")
    public void pointcut() {

    }

    @After("pointcut()")
    public void monitor() {
        System.out.println("*** AFTER TEST ***");
    }

}
```

Config :

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestAspect testAspect() {
        return new TestAspect();
    }

}
```

But my monitor method has not been invoked, what's wrong? Generally - can I advice test methods?? I want to know which test method has been invoked.

Comment: Why do you want to use aspects for this purpose? Simple maven log (assuming you are using maven) will tell you, if your test got executed. You could directly run the test suite through any good IDE and it will tell you which test got executed.

Comment: I want to check test method invocation and annotate some methods my custom annotation and in Aspect check whether test has this annotation or not

Comment: Add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your @Configuration class. See section 9.2 of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html.

Comment: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
 is already added in context.xml

Comment: Try it anyway. Configuration classes and xml configurations don't always play well together.

Comment: I've tried, nothing. I've googled and found that I can't make aspect around @Test because AppTest is created by SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, and there is no Proxy.

Comment: So it appears that the `@Component` on `AppTest` is ignored and Spring doesn't manage that class as a bean. I haven't worked with AspectJ outside of Spring AOP .. perhaps that could be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit itself has [Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) that can be used for this.

Comment: Rules are invoked before test invocation, but I would like to profile after.

Comment: They are enclosing the test invocation. You can act before and/or after. It is just like an aspect, without an external PointCut definition.